# Having a problem counting word occurrences in a collection of text documents

Tags: python, text, count

I have a large collection of text documents that I want to loop through and output a count of particular words in these documents in a simple dataframe of article title and word occurrence count. However my output dataframe is clearly incorrect. I suspect I'm doing something silly with the code. Would anyone be able to help identify the problem?

I collect the articles using the glob package and then loop through them using a count function. However my output is giving me patently wrong answers such as counts of '1' or '0' for the occurrences of simple things like the word "we" in very large documents.

```
import glob

articles = glob.glob('Test/*.txt')

we_dict = {}

for article in articles:
    we_dict[article] = article.count("we")

we = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(we_dict, orient='index', dtype=None)
```

There's no error messages produced, so the code is doing something - a dataframe is produced. But the count values outputted should be in the hundreds instead of small numbers such as 0, 1, 2.

**EDIT:**

Working version for future readers with the same query thanks to the very helpful responses. I'm sure the code could be simplified somewhat.

```
import glob
import re

articles = glob.glob('Test/*.txt')

we_dict = {}

for article in articles:
    with open(article, 'r', encoding="utf8") as art:
        a = art.read()
        a = a.lower()
        we_dict[article] = sum(1 for match in re.finditer(r"\bwe\b", a))

we = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(we_dict, orient='index', dtype=None)
```

Comment: You will need to ‘open’ each file and read it in and then count words.  It looks like you are counting words in the file names.

Comment: Hi there. Right now, your code is iterating through your list of articles and declaring `article` as the filename. The line `we_dict[article] = article.count("we")` is actually taking your filename and trying to find the word 'we' in the name itself! So what you'll need to do is open the file using the `filename` and then read the lines, searching for your word as you go.

Comment: Oh dear, I'm actually so embarassed over that. But also so thankful to you both!

Comment: Beware false positives. Currently you will count every occurrence of `'we'` even as a substring of other words, such as `'were'`. Consider using regular expressions, from the `re` module.

Comment: Thanks jez - I discovered that just a few minutes ago! Have updated the question with the working answer that has been double-checked for a manual count of a sample file for any future users with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, your code is iterating through your list of articles and declaring `article` as the filename. The line `we_dict[article] = article.count("we")` is actually taking your filename and trying to find the word 'we' in the name itself! So what you'll need to do is open the file using the `filename` and then read the lines.

One possible way to approach this is to read all the files into a dictionary and then go through that dict with counts of your word. Maybe like this:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

articles = glob.glob('*.txt')
txt_files = {}
word = 'cupcakes'

for article in articles:
    with open(article, 'r') as file:
        txt_files[article] = file.read().splitlines().count(word)

my_word = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(txt_files, orient='index')
```